# Why is my nested paginated query getting "multi-part identifier could not be bound" error?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, nested

I'm fairly new to SQL and I can't figure out what's wrong with my nested paginated query. I've been reading about this error but I could understand the explanation so I couldn't apply it in my case. I'm using MS SQL 2008. My tables are

[ContentDatabase].[dbo].[3DContent] has columns (ContentId, Name, PublishTypeId, CategoryId) and key is ContentId the table may have other columns that are irrelevant to the question

[ContentDatabase].[dbo].[SpecialCategoryMapping] has columns (ContentId, SpecialCategoryId) and no key since content can be in multiple categories but looking at my small data set i currently still have a one is to one relationship

[ContentDatabase].[dbo].[SpecialCategory] has columns (SpecialCategoryId, ParentCategoryId, Name) and SpecialCategoryId is the key and i'm not using ParentCategoryId yet in this query

Like a search functionality given a portion of a 3dcontent name, my goal is to return the columns of the 3DContent table together with its matching CategoryName as another concatenated column to the returned result. The name is retrieved from specialcategory table using the special category id resolved through the mapping table. So my query is below but its returning an error saying multipart identifier could not be bound...

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT A.[ContentId], A.[Name], A.[PublishTypeId], A.[CategoryId], B.[Name] as CategoryName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ContentID DESC) AS RowNum FROM [ContentDatabase].[dbo].[3DContent] AS A,
      (SELECT B.[Name] FROM [Contentatabase].[dbo].[SpecialCategory] as B WHERE B.[SpecialCategoryID] IN (SELECT * FROM [ContentDatabase].[dbo].[SpecialCategoryMapping] AS C WHERE C.[ContentID] = A.[ContentID])) AS D 
    WHERE A.Deleted = 0 AND A.PublishTypeId = 1 and A.[Name] like '%somepartialsearchstring%') as FinalTable 
 WHERE RowNum>=1 and RowNum<=6
```

There might be a totally better way to do this. I couldn't even check the result of my query coz this error is blocking me.

Thanks for the suggestion using join I have the following but it returning ambiguous column error seemingly pointing to ContentId,

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT A.[ContentId], A.[Name], A.[PublishTypeId], A.[CategoryId], A.[CategoryName], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ContentID DESC) AS RowNum FROM 
       (SELECT Z.[ContentId], Z.[Name], Z.[PublishTypeId], Z.[CategoryId], Y.[Name] as CategoryName FROM [ContentDatabase].[dbo].[3DContent] AS Z LEFT OUTER JOIN [ContentDatabase].[dbo].[SpecialCategoryMapping] AS Y ON Z.[ContentId] = Y.[ContentId]) AS A 
    WHERE A.Deleted = 0 AND A.PublishTypeId = 1 and A.[Name] like '%somepartialsearchstring%') as FinalTable 
 WHERE RowNum>=1 and RowNum<=6
```

After fixing some errors its pretty close to what I need, it's just returning null for all CategoryName, also I removed B.Name from the answer given by Unnikrishnan since table B doesn't contain a name column and A.Name is already selected anyway.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT A.[ContentId], A.[Name], A.[PublishTypeId] , A.[CategoryId], C.[Name] as CategoryName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.ContentID DESC) AS RowNum FROM [ContentDatabase].[dbo].[3DContent] AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN [ContentDatabase].[dbo].[SpecialCategoryMapping] AS B ON B.[ContentID] = A.[ContentID] LEFT OUTER JOIN [ContentDatabase].[dbo].[SpecialCategory] as C ON B.[SpecialCategoryID] = C.[SpecialCategoryID] 
    WHERE A.Deleted = 0 AND A.PublishTypeId = 1 and A.[Name] like '%somepartialsearchstring%') as FinalTable
WHERE RowNum>=1 AND RowNum<=6
```

The result looks something like this now

```
ContentId   Name    PublishTypeId   CategoryId  CategoryName RowNum
7594        Jet     1               12          NULL         1
```

But from the SpecialCategory table I can see that

```
SpecialCategoryID   Name
12                  Vehicles
```

So I was expecting Vehicles to be in CategoryName. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Looks like you want a JOIN https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below query..

If you need to select **category name** against the **specialcategoryid** in the table *[SpecialCategoryMapping]* against the **contentID** ,you can use the below script.

```
    SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT A.[ContentId], A.[Name], A.[PublishTypeId] , A.[CategoryId], C.[Name] as CategoryName
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.ContentID DESC) AS RowNum 
      FROM [ContentDatabase].[dbo].[3DContent] AS A 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN [ContentDatabase].[dbo].[SpecialCategoryMapping] AS B ON B.[ContentID] = A.[ContentID] 
          INNER JOIN [ContentDatabase].[dbo].[SpecialCategory] as C ON B.[SpecialCategoryID] = C.[SpecialCategoryID] 
    WHERE A.Deleted = 0 AND A.PublishTypeId = 1 and A.[Name] like '%somepartialsearchstring%') as FinalTable
WHERE RowNum>=1 AND RowNum<=6
```

If you need to select **category name** against the **categoryid** in the table *[3DContent]* , i think there is no need of table "*[SpecialCategoryMapping]*".

```
SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT A.[ContentId], A.[Name], A.[PublishTypeId] , A.[CategoryId], C.[Name] as CategoryName
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.ContentID DESC) AS RowNum 
          FROM [ContentDatabase].[dbo].[3DContent] AS A 
            JOIN [ContentDatabase].[dbo].[SpecialCategory] as C ON  A.[CategoryId] = C.[SpecialCategoryID] 
        WHERE A.Deleted = 0 AND A.PublishTypeId = 1 and A.[Name] like '%somepartialsearchstring%') as FinalTable
    WHERE RowNum>=1 AND RowNum<=6
```

Comment: After fixing some errors its pretty close to what I need, it's just returning null for all CategoryName, also I removed B.Name since table B doesn't contain a name column and A.Name is already selected. See the bottom of my updated post. Thanks again

Comment: Just make it as inner join and try it again.. see the updated script.

Comment: also make sure in the 'SpecialCategoryMapping' there is an entry for the required category (12) against that content 7594  . we are actually joining the SpecialCategoryID in the 'SpecialCategoryMapping' table with 'SpecialCategory' . NOT CategoryId form [3DContent] with 'SpecialCategory'.

Comment: ah i guess that's it, it suddenly became blank when i changed to inner join and it turns out there was No entry for 7594 in the specialcategorymapping. Thanks so much! Very helpful!